# Purpose of res.locals and req.flash()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the `connect-flash` npm package. For user autehntication I check the username or password coming from the form and populate the flash message accordingly.

Example:

```
req.flash('loginMessage', 'Incorrect Password')

req.flash('loginMessage', 'No username found')
```

And in the login page I render using :

```
router.get("/login", function (req, res) {
    //console.log(req.flash('error'))
    res.render("login", {
        message: req.flash('loginMessage')
    })
})
```

However, I have been seeing this a lot in other people's code:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.error=req.flash("error");
    res.locals.success=req.flash("success");
    next()
})
```

Express docs defines res.locals as

> An object that contains response local variables scoped to the
>   request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during
>   that request / response cycle (if any). Otherwise, this property is
>   identical to app.locals.

If the `locals` is deleted everytime similar to `flash` object. What is the difference between just using flash vs storing it in the locals variable?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is, `locals` is deleted *at the end of current request*, `flash` is deleted *after it is displayed*, and it is stored in session intermediately.

What that implies is, if at the end of the request no page is rendered (for example a redirection, a direct `res.end()`, etc.), your `locals` will be gone and lost, but on the other hand `flash` will still be retrievable because the use of session, which is persistent across requests.